# Tool like magic draw but for generate C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, uml

It's there a plugin for visual studio or a specific program that allows to draw an UML model and generates the classes for C#?? and more, for example Creates a repository classes from classes entities of the entity framework generates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has had the [Class Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33864ckt.aspx) built in since Visual Studio 2005, though not all versions (the Express versions don't have it).

Answer (score 1):

A former co-worker swore by http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html.  The generated code definitely needed some tweaking though. Or something like http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/index.php might have plugin's to generate needed c#...or perhaps t4.